# Basic Authentication using HTML5 (JQuery)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I would like to use a component (BasicAuthentication) that comes with HTML5 Builder from Embarcadero.

I used this component in PHP(Server side), not problem it is called as so:

```
$this->BasicAuthentication1->Execute();
```

This will generate a pop-up screen which as the user for user id and password.

I later found out this could not be done for (Client side), because the call must be in 
JavaScript or JQuery.  I have no idea how to do this? Can someone help me with an example?

I tried this, but it doesn't do nothing:

```
var component = jQuery('#BasicAuthentication1');
```

Comment: Basic auth it done at the webserver level, I'm not sure what you are asking for.

Comment: There is a component which I can drag into the design window called BasicAuthentication. I can call it using PHP $this->etc... as mentioned above.  This works well, when I open the browser in my test environment. It was meant for PHP(Server Side), but when I would like for my client side to see it, I need to display it using JQuery/JavaScript, but I don't know how the call is or should be?

Comment: You can't, the basic auth happens on the webserver not on the client. The whole point is that until the auth passes, you don't get the client code.

Comment: I follow you. I responded to duskwuff.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The pop-up that you're describing is not part of the web page, and cannot be manipulated by Javascript.

Comment: I am new to this, so maybe how I believe it should work and how it actually behaves are two different things.  Basically, I need to have an user sign in to a webserver module(NetBurner), and for the user to have to enter a username and password to get into it. I found the above, but if I would like to show it to a colleague of mine, he can't see it at his computer. After some reading, I found that only Javascripts or JQuery are client side tools that allow this.  That is why, I am looking to do the same as with the PHP line of code

Comment: What you've read is wrong. There is no way to have anyone other than the user enter that authentication data.

Comment: Ok, I think I follow you. The user is the only one that the authentication should pop-up for.  If I load the software in the webserver, then the client-side and the server-side will reside there.

Comment: I'm not certain you actually know what you're implementing here. You should probably read up on what HTTP Basic authentication is, and how it works. Once you understand that, you will understand why it cannot be implemented in Javascript.